# how to compare two list and find out `added` `deleted` `unchanged ` part

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I want this:

```
def compare_list(old, new):
    new_set = set(new)
    old_set = set(old)
    return new_set - old_set, old_set - new_set, new_set & old_set

old = [1, 2, 3]
new = [5, 4, 2, 3]

added, deleted, unchanged = compare_list(old, new)

print("added: ", added)
print("deleted: ", deleted)
print("unchanged: ", unchanged)
```

---

```
added:  {4, 5}
deleted:  {1}
unchanged:  {2, 3}
```

But it seems is very bad efficiency for me. So I want to know any more efficient solution? or build in function?

Comment: That seems pretty elegant to me. How are you determining that is has poor efficiency?

Comment: @MarkMeyer sorry i used the wrong word. I wonder it can be implement by for loop O（N）

Comment: This solution is O(N). Again, *what exactly is the problem with this solution*? This is the straightforward way, which uses built-in functionality. Seems fine to me.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am trying to create a find diff software which looks like `WinMerge`, and in my program, there are ton of places use this `compare_list` function, it looks like the bottom neck to me. So I looking for an efficient solution to improving the performance. `new_set - old_set, old_set - new_set, new_set & old_set` seems doing the related process.

Comment: @JustWe Is there a bound on the range of values of each element of list?

Comment: This solution assumes that the lists don't contain the same number multiple times.  If that is the case, perhaps you should use sets instead of lists in the rest of your program and save the list-to-set conversion step in the logic.  If the lists can contain duplicate values, then the solution doesn't work.

Comment: This would treat `[3,2]` as an unchanged version of `[2, 3]`. Real diff algorithms are more than just a set of set operations.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you could get extra speed by comparing the smaller intersection to the two larger lists rather than comparing them against each other.

```
def compare_list2(old, new):
    new_set = set(new)
    old_set = set(old)
    inter = new_set & old_set
    return new_set - inter, old_set - inter, inter

old = [1, 2, 3]
new = [5, 4, 2, 3]

#%time added, deleted, unchanged = compare_list(old, new)
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    compare_list2(old, new)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Is upto 0.3s faster than your function by only calculating the intersection once and using it twice.

```
--- 6.982441663742065 seconds ---
vs
--- 7.270233154296875 seconds ---
```

With respect to time complexity, we still have three passes over the data. We could sort first and then do a single pass, which yiels `O(n log n)`.
Python pseudocode, which is much slower but a C implementation would do. After sorting, this would be `O(n)`.

```
def compare_single_pass(old,new):
    new_set = sorted(new)
    old_set = sorted(old)
    added, deleted, unchanged = [],[],[]
    i, j = 0, 0
    j_max = len(old_set)
    i_max = len(new_set)
    while True:
        if i == i_max and j == j_max:
            return added, deleted, unchanged
            break
        if j == j_max:
            added.append(new_set[i])
            i += 1
            continue
        if i == i_max:
            deleted.append(old_set[j])
            j += 1
            continue
        if new_set[i] < old_set[j]:
            added.append(new_set[i])
            i += 1
            continue
        if new_set[i] == old_set[j]:
            unchanged.append(new_set[i])
            i += 1
            j += 1
            continue
        if new_set[i] > old_set[j]:
            deleted.append(old_set[j])
            j += 1
            continue
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that O(n log n) is slower than O(3n) (which translates to O(n) )

Answer (score -1):

```
def compareList(old, new):

    added = []
    deleted = []
    unchanged = []
    
    position = 0
    while position <= len(new)-1:
        if new[position] in old:
            unchanged.append(new[position])
        elif new[position] not in old:
            added.append(new[position])
        
        position += 1

    index = 0
    while index <= len(old)-1:
        if old[index] not in new:
            deleted.append(old[index])

        index += 1

    return f"added: {added}, deleted: {deleted}, unchanged: {unchanged}"

old = [1, 2, 3]
new = [5, 4, 2, 3]

x = compareList(old, new)
print(x)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).